# Time-series data in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, streaming, time-series

I need to model 1,000,000+ data points in JSON. I am thinking of two ways of doing this:

a) Array of objects:

```
[{time:123456789,value:1432423},{time:123456790,value:1432424},....]
```

or

b) Nested arrays

```
[[123456789,1432423],[123456790,1432424],....]
```

Naively comparing these two approaches, it feels like the latter is faster because it uses less characters but less descriptive. Is b really faster than a ? Which one would you choose and why ?

Is there a 3rd approach ?

Comment: Faster in which respect? Creating the output? Parsing? Transferring? Plus, IMHO, 1M+ entries screams for some other form of representation.

Comment: Faster on parsing at client side

Comment: Well, then **test** both approaches and **decide** based on hard-facts ( sub-usec timing, transport & processing latency, peak resources consumption, deferred garbage-collection issues )

Answer (score 11):

```
{time:[123456789,123456790,...], value:[1432423,1432424,...]}
```

why?

1. iterating over a primitive array is faster.
2. comparable to "JSON size" with b) but you will not lose the "column" information

this npm could be of interest: https://github.com/michaelwittig/fliptable

Answer (score 2):

If your time series data models some continuous function, especially over regular time intervals, there could be much more efficient representation with delta compression, even if you are still using JSON:

```
[
    {time:10001,value:12345},
    {time:10002,value:12354},
    {time:10003,value:12354},
    {time:10010,value:12352}
]
```

Can be represented as:

```
[[10001,1,1,7],[12345,9,,-2]]
```

Which is a 4 times shorter representation.

The original could be reconstructed with:

```
[{time:a[0][0],value:a[1][0]},{time:a[0][0] + a[0][1]||1, value: a[1][0] + a[1][1]||0 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

To add another example (idea: 'time is a key'):

```
ts1 = {123456789: 1432423, 123456790: 1432424}
```

One could imagine even:

```
ts2 = {"2017-01-01": {x: 2, y: 3}, "2017-02-01": {x: 1, y: 5}}
```

Quite compact in notation.

When you want to get the keys, use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
Object.keys(ts2) // ["2017-01-01", "2017-02-01"]
```

You can then either get the values by iterating using these keys or use the more experimental [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```
Object.values(ts2) // [{x: 2, y: 3}, {x: 1, y: 5}
```

In terms of speed: A quick test with 10.000.000 items in an array worked here:

```
obj3 = {}; 
for(var i=0; i < 10000000; i++) {obj3[i] = Math.random()};
console.time("values() test");
Object.values(obj3); 
console.timeEnd("values() test");
console.time("keys() test");
Object.keys(obj3); 
console.timeEnd("keys() test");
```

Results at my machine (Chrome, 3.2Ghz Xeon):

- values() test: 181.77978515625ms
- keys() test: 1230.604736328125ms

Comment: Sidenote: Note that when both the keys are of the same type and they follow a typical order and the object hasn't been touched you probably can assume that the order is as inserted. But when you modify the object this assumption no longer holds: objects have no order. When order is important check the new [Map](http://2ality.com/2015/08/es6-map-json.html) structure, which is initiated with an array of pairs, or nested arrays, exactly like the 2nd suggestion by the question-author)